# How to dumb-down python auto-indentation in sublime text 3

Tags: python, text-editors, sublime-text-2

I am using Sublime Text 3, and the auto-indent is a problem for me.  Basically, all I want is auto-indent to the same indent level as the previous line, similar to gedit's dumb but predictable behavior.  But Sublime Text's auto-indenter adds an additional tab (=an additional four spaces) after a colon (for instance, after `class SomeClass(...):`).

I thought this was what the `smart_indent` option was for, but unfortunately disabling that doesn't seem to disable this feature.  Disabling `auto_indent` altogether, of course, turns off even the dumb indentation.

Is there any way to configure Sublime Text to stop doing this, or even override that behavior with a custom plugin?

(I wanted to post this with a sublime-text-3 tag, but it does not exist yet.  For what it's worth, the configuration options and their documentation is identical in Sublime Text 2, so behavior may be identical too.)

Comment: have you tried setting `smart_indent` to false in Sublime Text 2 to see if that works? ST3 in my experience is still lacking a number of features, so this just might not be implemented yet. (And besides - I **like** smart indent!)

Comment: I have not tried Sublime Text 2, but I'm willing to give it a shot if it might fix this issue.